# processing a seq until a pred function is true

Tags: clojure, sequence

I am processing a sequence in clojure. I would like to retrieve elements until a predicate function is true. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `take-while` along with `not`

```
user=> (take-while (comp not even?) [3 9 2 4 6 10 1 2])
(3 9)
```

Comment: I'd say `not` is not obligatory here. `(take-while odd? [3 9 2 4 6 10 1 2])` is just as good.

Comment: Actually I mentioned `not` because the questions seems to indicate that there is already a predicate which returns true but the user want to use it to 'take while the predicate returns false' or 'take until the predicate returns true'

Comment: `comp not` can be expressed as `complement`.